# iOS 14 Widget: Click item to open app page on Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, deep-linking, cordova-ios

I have a Project which is build on Cordova, recently I have developed the widget for ios 14.
Target: when the user click on the widget Article Item, I want console.log() or catch the URL on the Cordova project so that I can user redirect to the Article Page.

In the project Already code exist which takes care of deeplink. But whenever, I click on the widget item My app launches.
For Example : if click on the article link  from the Slack Application. User will land on the corresponding Article.

I am using  this plugins
[cordova-universal-links-plugin](https://github.com/bayard-lacroix/cordova-universal-links-plugin), [cordova-plugin-customurlscheme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme)

Regarding the Widget Native code I followed the documentation [Creating widget](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension)
and i am using the [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Link) method WidgetFamily.systemMedium or WidgetFamily.systemLarge, for other widgets  i am using
[widgetURL(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/widgetURL(_:))

```
Link(destination: URL(string: urlString)!,label: {
                   Text(article.Title != nil ? article.Title! : "test")
                       .lineLimit(3)
                       .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
                       .padding()
               })
```

`.widgetURL(URL(string: article.URL != nil ? article.URL! : ""))`

on cordova APP I have

```
// Custom url scheme : cordova-plugin-customurlscheme
    window.handleOpenURL = url => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        main.onOpenApplicationLinks(url)
      }, 0)
    }
```

```
 // Universal Link Cordova Plugin
    universalLinks.subscribe('openPath', (eventData)=> console.log(eventData))
```

How can Catch the URL or Log the URL on the cordova App
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some days of research. I finally made change to the cordova-universalLink-Plugin.
In plugin Appdelegate+CULPlugin.m  add

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"] || [url.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        NSUserActivity *activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb];
        [activity setWebpageURL:url];
        
        CULPlugin *plugin = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:PLUGIN_NAME];
        return [plugin handleUserActivity:activity];
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
    
}
```

Voila...,now it works

Comment: life saver thanks, not sure why this is even needed. also should have it added to docs for the cordova plugin.